# associating a "People or Group" column with a group that contain Everyone will not autocomplete any users

Tags: 2013, list, development, groups, people-search

I have created a group named "Intranet Visitors" that contain Everyone as follow:-

[image]

Then i associated a site column of type "People or Group" with the security group, as follow:-

[image]

but now when i search for users inside the site column , the site column will not show any result (no result are being shown in the autocomplete), although it should include Everyone,, can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: if you are adding everyone to SharePoint group then is there any specific need to bind that group to SharePoint column(as if you don't bind it then also all users can be found in people picker?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela i am using the default New & Edit forms so there is not any people picker, instead i have the auto complete feature,, but the autocomplete will always return no results found in my case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a distinction between given access to a group of people using the "Everyone" group and being able to resolve their usernames.

In your case you should be able to resolve "everyone", but since SharePoint doesn't really resolve AD groups, you can't see who's member of the group. Ironically given permissions based on AD groups works just fine.

To be able to do what you're trying the actual useraccounts would have to be member of the Visitor group.

Comment: so i need to manually add all our users to the group ,, is this what you mean ?

Comment: If you want to limit the user field to a specific group and you want to be able to resolve their usernames, than yes.
Of course you got also use PowerShell to help you with the task.